# Controlling logic gate and dead time for H-bridge MOSFETs

Tags: logic-gates, mosfet-driver, h-bridge, schmitt-trigger, dead-time

I intend to make an H-bridge driver for a 36v DC motor that can control with 3 MCU pins (Enable, PWM, Direction), Regarding my research, there are three options to drive the H MOSFETs; One using the pul-pull BJT to drive the high side and low side, similar to the following image

[image]

The other available option is using the MOSFET gate driver, however, I found two types of the gate (half bridge) drivers. One has direct H&L input control pins and the other has Enable and PWM input signal.

NAND and Schmitt trigger inverters have been used to control the H&L input pins with En, PWM, and Direction pin

[image]

I didn't design that logic gate for controlling the H&L gates and I know controlling the MOSFET dead-time is crucial.

Despite the above gate driver, a gate driver with En & PWM pins has a feature to control the dead-time (the following image)

[image]

My questions are:

How can I control dead-time in design figures 1 & 2?

What is the functionality of using multiple Schmitt trigger inverters in Figures 1 & 2 and why are they pulled down?

Can I use the same logic gate for Figure number 3?

Despite the cost which of those design more reliable for H-bridge application.